# dojox.mobile Switch in ListItem

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.mobile

I'm quite new to dojo and trying to work out how to do something programatically rather than declaratively.  I can easily create a dojox.mobile.RoundRectList containing a dojox.mobile.ListItem that itself contains a dojox.mobile.switch declaratively, e.g.

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
<li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="icon:'../../app/images/i-icon-1.png'">
    Airplane Mode
    <div class="mblItemSwitch" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Switch"></div>
</li>
```

This is from the getting started guide here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/demo/

What I want to do is dynaically generate the list items each with their own dynamically generated button.  The following code does that ('list' is an array of objects I've made earlier in the code and 'ListElement' is a declaratively placed dojox.mobile.RoundRectList):

```
var listObj = dijit.byId("ListElement");
for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {

    var item = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
        id: "item" + list[n].ID,
        label: list[n].Name
    });

    var sw = new dojox.mobile.Switch({
        className: "mblItemSwitch"
    });
    item.addChild(sw);

    listObj.addChild(item);

}
```

However, unlike in the declarative example where the switch is placed on the right hand side of the list item, the switch is just placed on the left hand side and overlays the text.

Can anyone advise how I can achieve the correct placement of the switch?  I'm quite prepared to accept there is a better way of doing this entirely (as I'm pretty new to dojo) but haven't been able to find an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first time ever, but I've found the answer myself.  Looks like the example I'd cribbed this from was either wrong, or in a slightly different context.  Instead of using className when declaring the switch it should just be class.  e.g.

```
    var sw = new dojox.mobile.Switch({
        class: "mblItemSwitch"
    });
```

The switch then appears correctly formatted and aligned to the right.